# cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks : export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T : never;

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, cordova-plugins, firebase-dynamic-links

Having issue in setuping firebase dynamic link in my ionic project.

Steps are described which I follow for setup this plugin :

1. Install the plugin using

   ```
   ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks --save --variable APP_DOMAIN="example.com" --variable PAGE_LINK_DOMAIN="example.page.link"
   ```
2. Install the NPM package for this using

   ```
   npm install @ionic-native/firebase-dynamic-links
   ```
3. Added below code to my app.component.ts file

   ```
   import { FirebaseDynamicLinks } from '@ionic-native/firebase-dynamic-links/ngx';

   constructor(private firebaseDynamicLinks: FirebaseDynamicLinks) { }

   ...
   // Handle the logic here after opening the app with the Dynamic link
   this.firebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink()
     .subscribe((res: any) => console.log(res), (error:any) => console.log(error));
   ```

After that I tried to build my project and suddenly got an error :

```
vendor.js:2135 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at FirebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink (vendor.js:93256)
    at main.js:1006
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:5446)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:5437)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:5437)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at o (polyfills.js:3)
defaultErrorLogger @ vendor.js:2135
```

To remove this error, I googled some blogs and got a link through remove this using

```
npm i rxjs@^6.0 rxjs-compat
```

After that I build my project again, Now i got some strange error :

```
[16:34:53]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 81
             'ObservableInput' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ? T : never;
```

I googled but can't solve this.

I tried to remove node_modules and install again and doing same for platform but it persist yet.

Here is my environment info :

```
✔ Gathering environment info - done!
Ionic:
ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
Cordova:
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1, ios 4.5.4
Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 15 other plugins)
System:
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/anandmahajan/Library/Android/sdk)
ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
NodeJS            : v8.11.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install  `npm install rxjs@6.3.3 --save`, then it would be solved.

Comment: Ok I'll try once.

Answer (score 0):

solved it, by npm install rxjs@6.0.0 --save

Comment: Try to explain why the issue is being caused as well. Rather than jumping to the solution, it would help the users to understand why your solution will solve the issue at hand